# Bottom 3-5 item main navigation with "more"

Tags: mobile, navigation, web-app, cross-platform

I'm about to design a responsive mobile web UI with bottom navigation with 5 items of which the last one is the *More...* item that should open a list of additional ones that are secondary to user processes.

What would be the best cross mobile platform way of displaying these additional items? Should they be opened as

- a full screen list,
- a bottom aligned list going as high as there are items
- a popup bottom-right aligned menu or
- any better way?

I don't know which way would be best? Each of these items will completely switch application window context so full-screen or bottom full-width list seem to be the most appropriate?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to follow this pattern, and I would caution your use of it (see below), the standard way is to provide a full screen list.  [Facebook's iOS app](https://techcrunch.com/2013/09/18/facebooks-new-mobile-test-framework-births-bottom-tab-bar-navigation-redesign-for-ios-5-6-7/) is a good example.

I would use this pattern with caution as tabbed bottom navigation is typical of native apps and rarely used in web apps. Android recently added this as [an acceptable pattern](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-navigation.html#) and [iOS](https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/ui-bars/tab-bars/) has traditionally used the "More" tab for a list of additional items. (you might look to their guidelines for ideas)

It might be perfectly applicable to what you're trying to do and if so great! But users tend to expect slightly different navigation schemes from web apps.

Comment: I'm not developing a native app, but my app is a web based mobile-only app. So it will still be used only on mobile devices. That's the reason I would like to optimize it as such. Although Android's material design guidelines also show the [bottom navigation](https://material.google.com/components/bottom-navigation.html) they discourage its use because of the close proximity to system buttons.

Comment: A full screen menu seems all right, but I'm sure there must be some limitations to the number of items in the list. If it's one then there's no need for the *more...* button. If there're two (or maybe even three), a full screen menu seems unreasonable doesn't it?

Comment: When you say web-based mobile only do you mean an app inside a wrapper like Ionic? I don't think a full screen menu is unreasonable with a few items simply because that's the behavior that's expected.